# How to change the attribute value in class without calling the method in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, project

I was doing this Pokemon project on Codecademy, and it asked me to do something that I was completely unable to think of, as I don't have much practice on OOPS and python.

How can I set `is_knocked_out = True`, without calling any method on my instance? I think that my code should know automatically when the health of pokemon has become zero and automatically change its attribute `is_knocked_out` to `True`.
I searched online but didn’t find any definitive solution maybe it has something to do with decorators.

Can someone please explain me how to do this, because I think I might have hit a wall here.

I have written the following code so far:

```
class Pokemon:

    def __init__(self,name,level,ptype,is_knocked_out= False):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.type = ptype
        self.max_health = level
        self.curr_health = max_health
        self.is_knocked_out = is_knocked_out

    def lose_health(self,loss_amount):
        self.curr_health -= loss_amount
        print(f"{self.name} has now health of {self.curr_health}")

    def regain_health(self,gain_amount):
        self.curr_health += gain_amount
        print(f"{self.name} has now health of {self.curr_health}")

    #@property
    def knock_out(self):
        if self.curr_health <=0:
            self.is_knocked_out = True
            print(f"{self.name} has been knocked out")
```

Comment: Just assign `True` to that attribute: `p = Pokemon( ... ); p.is_knocked_out = True`

Comment: I mean when i further write this code and the health of my pokemon decreases and eventually raches zero i don't want to explicitly do that, but i want that it happens automatically when health reaches zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach is to make `is_knocked_out` a `property` so its value can always be computed from `curr_health`:

```
class Pokemon:
    ...

    @property
    def is_knocked_out(self):
        return self.curr_health <= 0
```

Comment: If i make it a property then it cannot remain an attribute right, we can just access it as attribute. Also in this case i need to do "instance.is_knocked_out", then only it will set it to True, cannot my code auto assign that in some way such that when health = 0, is_knocked_out already becomes true?

Comment: @BhavikRoopchandani It's exactly as you describe, every time you access `is_knocked_out` it will be computed dynamically based on `curr_health`. So if `curr_health <= 0` then `is_knocked_out is True`.